# How do you say this math expression in English (UK)?

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

> (3x + 1)<sup>2</sup> - x<sup>2</sup>

How do you say it?

So this is pronounce ‘bracket three x plus one bracket square minus x square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maths expressions aren't English, and when you read them you just read out each character. Note that the small two is read "squared" (small three is "cubed" and small 4 or higher powers are read as "to the power 4")

so "Bracket three x plus one close-bracket squared minus x squared"

Comment: I wanna ask one more question. What’s the difference between ‘How would you say it?’ and ‘How do you say it?’ ? Thank you!

Comment: If you have a new question you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: @user280923 This answer to [How would you like your coffee?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/40269/) might be helpful. There are quite a few questions about "would" and "do" that might interest you if you look through the questions tagged [tag:modal-verbs], like [What is the difference between “do you like” and “would you like”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/29804/)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how exactly they would say it in the UK, but here's yet another mathematically legal way to verbalize that:

> Three x plus one quantity squared minus x squared.

So, you list out one by one all the things that you have in parentheses and then to indicate that you want to square all of what you just listed out, you just say *quantity squared* or *entire quantity squared* and follow that with the rest of your math expression.

A more traditional way of saying it would be:

> Open parenthesis three x plus one close parenthesis whole thing squared minus x squared.

Comment: Regarding reading out the parentheses, it's also fairly common to just use 'paren' and ' close paren', "paren three eks plus one close paren squared minus eks squared"

Answer (score 0):

As a mathematician, if I had to say out loud that expression I would not attempt to dictate it symbol by symbol, but rather I would say a bit more about the structure: "The difference between two squares three x +1 squared minus x squared."